# Long usernames overflow revision list headers

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list, display-names

When a user has a long name without spaces, their name overflows the revision header, as can be seen e.g. [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/110286/revisions):

[image]

Comment: How should this be corrected, in your opinion? Should the name be cut off arbitrarily into multiple lines or truncated?

Comment: Good question - on Q&A pages, the cut off is arbitrary, cf. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/121204/13666 so it's logical to extend that to other pages.